# How to use Windows command in CMake (CMakeLists.txt)?

Tags: linux, windows, cmake

As CMake doesn't provide the command like 'cmake clean'. So we have to write our own way of custom command for clean.

I have following command('cmake distclean') for the linux platform.

```
add_custom_command(
    COMMENT "distribution clean"
    COMMAND make
    ARGS -C ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} clean
    COMMAND find
    ARGS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} -name "CMakeCache.txt" | xargs rm -rf
    COMMAND find
    ARGS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} -name "CMakeFiles" | xargs rm -rf
    COMMAND find
    ARGS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} -name "Makefile" | xargs rm -rf
    TARGET  distclean
)
```

The same thing I tried to do on Windows but couldn't get any success.

```
add_custom_command(
    COMMENT "distribution clean"
    COMMAND nmake
    ARGS -C ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} clean
    FOR /F %k in
    'COMMAND dir ARGS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} /s /b "CMakeCache.txt"' DO rmdir /s /q %k
    FOR /F %k in
    'COMMAND dir ARGS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} /s /b "CMakeFiles"' DO rmdir /s /q %k
    FOR /F %k in
    'COMMAND dir ARGS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} /s /b "Makefile"' DO rmdir /s /q %k
    TARGET  distclean
)
```

Is there any alternatives to do? And how to use Windows command in CMake or how can we use in `CMakeLists.txt` like we do in Linux?

Comment: *"distribution clean"* is usually the `distclean` target in a makefile. `clean` is usually a separate recipe. Also see [GNU Coding Standards | Standard Targets for Users](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Standard-Targets.html)

Comment: @jww: It seems that the first `cmake clean` is a misprint, all further description is about `make distclean`. The code has a line `TARGET distclean`, which means that corresponded commands are executed on `make distclean`. But let the author to fix that inconsistence...

Comment: "The same thing I tried to do on Windows but couldn't get any success." - What exact error do you get? Note, that `COMMAND` is an option to `add_custom_command`, you cannot call it in `FOR` cycle in the shell script. If you have problems in writing shell commands inside CMake, then you may create a **separate shell script**, and call it from CMake. Also, the most effective `make distclean` is removing the build directory; it assumes that you have out-of-source build, which is recommended in the most cases.